# relation "org_user_orguser" does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to do a migration in Django 1.8.

The migration looks like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations

def update_email_username(apps, schema_editor):
    user_id = 'the-uuid-will-go-here'
    OrgUser = apps.get_model("org_user", "OrgUser")
    for person in OrgUser.objects.filter(user_id=user_id):
        person.username = "person@email.com"
        person.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('org_user', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(update_email_username),
    ]
```

And I get:

```
django.db.migrations.graph.CircularDependencyError: org_user.0001_initial
```

I've also tried

```
dependencies = [
    ('org_user', '__first__'),
]
```

and I get:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "org_user_orguser" does not exist
```

But there is absolutely a model for org_user, and it is in my settings.py.

What exactly is going on here with my migration? How do I successfully run the changes listed in this migration?

This is in Postgres if that helps.

EDIT:

When I temporarily delete the migration, and recreate the database, everything creates fine (including org_user), if I then try to add the migration back to the /migration directory of the model and run it, I get the error: `LookupError: No installed app with label 'org_user'.`

Comment: What are the contents of the `org_user.0001_initial` migration? What is the name of the migration that is failing? It might help if you show the `OrgUser` model as well. The 'relation does not exist' error doesn't mean the the model hasn't been defined, it means that the table has not been created in your database yet. The notes on [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22932#comment:4) might help you untangle the circular dependency error.

Comment: Please show all the models

Comment: org_user.0001_initial migration is the migration above - it is located at /org_user/migration/0001_initial.py. Do you just want the models only, @pynchia? There are ten.

Comment: My guess is that the initial error is because it IS 0001_initial. Which is why I changed it to __first__ - which seems to be the correct value to indicate the first migration?

Answer (score 0):

I dont really know, if I understand you correctly...
Usually, from a fresh project start, it works like this:

1. You define your models in models.py
2. You call `manage.py makemigrations`
3. Your first (initial) migration will be created. It shouldn't have any dependencies within its own package
4. Everytime you make changes to your model, you need to call `manage.py makemigrations` and a new migration will be created automatically in the migrations folder.

If you have multiple packages, the automatically generated migrations usuall take the last migration from each package as a dependency. If you don't want to do any datamigrations or anything, there should be no need to care about the dependencies.

You can find more information [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#workflow)

Initial migrations should always be generated automatically with the

```
makemigrations
```

Command

EDIT: Are you sure you don't want to have:

```
('orguser',  '0001_initial')
```

?

Comment: the model name is org_user so I don't think so.

Comment: wait... The model name or the module/package name? Can you post your project structure? You need to specify the module name as the first argument in the dependencies (the name of the app/folder containing the initial migration you are referring to)